# How to use a non-string ref without causing flow errors

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I see that string refs are legacy in react:
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-string-refs.md

But I am getting this flow error in my component and don't know how to resolve it:

```
[flow] Cannot assign `c` to `this.loginform` because property `loginform` is missing in `LoginScreen` [1]. (References: [1])
```

My component:

```
/**
 * @flow
 */

// ... imports, tcomb form model, etcetera ...

class LoginScreen extends React.Component<*> {

  onPress() {
    var creds = this.loginform.getValue();
    orbRequestLogin(this.props.navigation, creds, '/oauth/token');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrap bgcolor="white">
        <Content>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
            <Form ref={(c) => { this.loginform = c; }} type={User} options={options} />

            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log in</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>

          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </Content>
      </Wrap>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(LoginScreen);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an annotation for `loginform` within the body of your class. That is:

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component<*> {
    loginform: Form
```

This is described in the [Class Fields](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/#toc-class-fields-properties) section of the flow docs.

Comment: Thanks!  Somehow I completely missed this feature.